# Moving the method to another class make it stop working

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

I have this class called Screen

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import AnimatorHandler.FishAnimation;
import data.*;
import save.Data;

public class Screen extends JPanel{
    
    Resources res = new Resources();
    Background background = new Background();
    Ground ground = new Ground();
    Animal animal = new Animal(null, null, 0, null, 0, 0);
    FishAnimation fA = new FishAnimation();
    
    int screenSizeX = 1099;
    int screenSizeY = 735;
    
    void createWindow() throws IOException {
        
        //CREATION OF THE RESOURCES
        background.createBackground();
        ground.createGround();
        animal.createAnimal();
        
        //SETTING OF THE LAYEREDPANE
        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, screenSizeX, screenSizeY);
        layeredPane.add(background.background[Data.selectedBackground], Integer.valueOf(0));
        layeredPane.add(ground.ground[Data.selectedGround], Integer.valueOf(1));
        layeredPane.add(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal], Integer.valueOf(2));
        layeredPane.add(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1], Integer.valueOf(2));
           
        //SETTING OF THE FRAME
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Happy Aquarium");
        frame.add(layeredPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(screenSizeX, screenSizeY));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        //ANIMATION
        fA.action();
        
    }
}
```

And I just tried to export the `fA.action()` in another class (before the export was called just `action`, created automatically by `ActionListener`) So I just cut and paste the method to the `Screen` class to the `FishAnimation` class.

```
package AnimatorHandler;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.Timer;

import data.Animal;
import save.Data;

public class FishAnimation implements ActionListener{
    
    Animal animal = new Animal(null, null, 0, null, 0, 0);
    Timer timer;
    
    public void action() throws IOException {
        animal.createAnimal();
        
        timer = new Timer(1, this);
        timer.start();
            
         
          
          
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        

        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getY() >= 260 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getY()<-300) {
            
            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].setYVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getYVelocity() * -1);
        }
        
        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getX() >= 456 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getX()<-456) {
            
            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].setXVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getXVelocity() * -1);
            
        }
        animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].setBounds(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getX() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getXVelocity(), animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal].getY() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal].getYVelocity(), 1083, 696);

        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getY() >= 260 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getY()<-300) {
            
            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].setYVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getYVelocity() * -1);
        }
        
        if(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getX() >= 456 || animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getX()<-456) {

            animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].setXVelocity(animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getXVelocity() * -1);
            
        }
        animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].setBounds(animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getX() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getXVelocity(), animal.animals[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getY() + animal.animali[Data.selectedAnimal+1].getYVelocity(), 1083, 696);
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

So I called the `action` method from this new class to the `Screen` class and nothing it stop working

I tried google it but nothing, I tried to call the method in the `Main` class instead of the `Screen` class, but still nothing, BUT if I import again the exported `action` method to the `Screen` class, it works again.

Comment: You need to pass the `animal` created in `Screen`  object to your `FishAnimation` object, preferably via the constructor.

Comment: @JanezKuhar can you make me an example?